# Polish language is not loading in the browser - ngx translate

Tags: angularjs, ngx-translate, polish

i am new to angular so not sure which piece of code should be included here. I am using ngx translate, and building an application with angularjs. this application is multilingual and loads other languages like german and chinese, but i am facing issue only with Polish. the json data is being loaded in the network tab, but its not reflecting in the browser.

1. wanted to know if by default ngx-translate supports polish language.
2. if not then is there any alternative method to support this language?
3. if yes then please let me know what piece of code i can add to get suggestions.